# variable defined in wordpress template header inaccessible below get_header

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following, to run a simple form in the very top of my wordpress theme header.php file:

```
<?php
//deal with theme embeded forms
if ($_POST['enquery_page_loop']) {
    $call_time = $_POST['call_time'];
    $f_name = $_POST['r_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

    $admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
    $message = "A callback request has been recieved.\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "Name: ".$f_name."\r\n";
    $message .= "Time to Call: ".$call_time."\r\n";
    $message .= "Email: ".$email."\r\n";
    $message .= "Phone: ".$phone."\r\n";

    mail ($admin_email, "A Callback request was recieved via the website", $message, 'FROM:'.$admin_email);
    $loop_mail_done = '1';
    echo $loop_mail_done;
}
?>
```

After I call `<?php get_header(); ?>` in the page.php file, the `$loop_mail_done;` variable is completely inaccessible, as if it was never defined. Yet when I echo it from the bottom of the header.php file, it is defined correctly.

I'm at a loss to understand how I am losing this variable. 
I've checked / tried:

- declaring `global $loop_mail_done;` in the page.php
- correct scope (as far as I can see)
- checked for `unset` or similar actions on the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
global $loop_mail_done;
```

in **both** page.php and header.php before using this variable.

Comment: Cheers! BTW do you know why I fell out of scope?

Comment: No, not an expert in Wordpress internals :)

Answer (score 2):

As has been said using

```
global $loop_mail_done;
```

in both of the files will sort out the problem.

The reason for the issue is that both header.php and the page.php/index.php etc are invoked by functions upon page rendering.  Whilst it looks to you like you've written something in the same scope, they are actually two variables in two seperate functions.

An alternative is to use $GLOBALS to store the variable, but declaring it global does as well.